# Book on linear (mixed) models in statistics

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, references, linear-model

My actual field is biology, although I need to do plenty of linear regressions. I consider myself to have an undergraduate level of maths. Lately, I am facing the usage of linear mixed models, and I feel a bit lost.

Could you recommend me some book, with as much practice as possible, in which linear models and, particularly, linear mixed models are explained with examples?

Comment: Judith Singer's paper *Using SAS Proc Mixed to Fit Multilevel Models* is the single best intro paper to this class of models that I'm aware of (https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf). Good books include her's with Willett *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis*, Gelman and Hill's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. All of the above have many applied examples.

Comment: I highly endorse Regression Methods in Biostatistics by Vittinghoff et al. The book is the only of its class that discuss conditional methods, like mixed effects and conditional logistic regression, at a level accessible by nonstatisticians. The focus is on rationale and interpretation rather than writing down likelihood equations.

Answer (score 1):

Although I've never read this one, I've heard good reviews of it and it seems to perfectly fit your purpose (although you haven't specified the software on which you rely). Here's a link for the book, on Amazon - [Linear Mixed Models: A Practical Guide Using Statistical Software 1st Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584884800)